# How to create HTML Form in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
// open a new window. Create and submit form
function createSubmitForm(response) {
    var external = window.open('about:blank', 'external');
    var doc = external.document;
    var body = $('body', doc);

    // create a new form element
    var form = $("<form id='authForm'></form>");
    // set the form's attributes and add to iframe
    form.attr("action", response.action)
        .attr("method", response.method);
    form.appendTo(body);

    // create form elements;
    for (var i = 0, len = response.fields.length; i < len; i++) {
        var field = response.fields[i];

        if (field.name != "") {
            $("<input type='hidden'/>")
                .attr("name", field.name)
                .attr("value", field.value)
                .appendTo(form);
        }
    }
    // submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

When I try to execute it, I get an **"Unspecified Error"** at `form.appendTo(body)`.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I want to open a new window, create a form inside that window, then submit it. If I use the same approach with an iFrame, it works.

Comment: Try doing a `document.write` on the new window.

Comment: I'd only consider that if I can not do it with jQuery. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Please notice that You must have a blank page on Your server http://localhost/some-blank-page-on-your-server.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
(function($) {
$(function() {
    // open a new window. Create and submit form
    function createSubmitForm(response) {
        var external = window.open('http://localhost/some-blank-page-on-your-server.php', 'external');
setTimeout(function() {
        var doc = external.document;
        var body = $('body', doc);

        // create a new form element
        var form = $("<form id='authForm'></form>");
        // set the form's attributes and add to iframe
        form.attr("action", response.action)
            .attr("method", response.method);


        // create form elements;
        for (var i = 0, len = response.fields.length; i < len; i++) {
            var field = response.fields[i];

            if ( field.name !== "" ) {
                $("<input type='text'/>")
                    .attr("name", field.name)
                    .attr("value", field.value)
                    .appendTo(form);
            }
            $("<input type='submit' value='submit' />").appendTo(form);
        }
        // submit the form
        form.submit();

        body.append(form);
}, 1000);
    }

    createSubmitForm({
      action: 'http://www.example.com',
      method: 'get',
      fields: [{
        name: 'field1',
        value: 'some value'
      }]
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `body.append(form)` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Does Your Browser block Pop-ups?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get an error this time, but still doesn't work. BTW, I had to move `body.append(form)` before `form.submit()`.

Comment: I've tested it in an environment with IE6. It's wired. I changed setTimeout to $(doc).ready(function() {...}); (it was better). When I tried to add some content with jQuerys append() I got some strange error (I don't remember now). Then I tried to append content with innerHTML. It worked - I could see the form. And here is the tricky part: I couldn't fire the submit event. I couldn't do it even by pressing the submit button although the action was set (I checked, the action param is there).

Comment: Maybe @ShankarSangoli is right in saying that this will not work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use document.write when you want to write in a new window. The way you are doing will not work in all the browsers.

Comment: At this moment, I only need it to work in IE. Is IE one of those browsers that will not work?

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery to define the form when appending

$(form).appendTo(body);

Comment: I am already doing that with: `var form = $("<form id='authForm'></form>");`. Unless I did not understand you correctly?

Comment: im afraid to respond because some users get all mad if your wrong... but i was under the impression that since appendTo is a jquery function that the line of code must begin with a $
$(form).appendTo(body);
not
form.appendTo(body);

Comment: No worries... I'm not one of those users. However, I doubt that will change anything.

Answer (score 0):

i think a simpler approach is to use [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

I would throw an alert(form) just before the appendTo just to see what the page thinks the form variable is at that point.

Another option to help pinpoint the issue would be loading firebug in firefox and use this to debug the problem.   As a quick test I would get rid of the camelcase though since I've had instances before where  even though it is supposed to be camelcase it only works when it is all lower case.  Usually this is in IE.  silly, but it is a quick check.