# Creating and submitting form in new window - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to create new form in a new page and have it submitted. I've picked up this snippet from [How to create HTML Form in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835422/how-to-create-html-form-in-a-new-window).
But it's only opening a new window with the URL in the action and not submitting the form automatically:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ajax_example2 = {
        attach: function(context) {

         jQuery("#btn1").click(

            function () {

                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", "post");
                form.setAttribute("action", 'http://moodle.foresteee.com/login/index.php');

// setting form target to a window named 'formresult'
                form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("username", "testaccount1@wo");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("password", "forest3");
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                document.body.appendChild(form);

// creating the 'formresult' window with custom features prior to submitting the form
                window.open('test.html', 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');

                form.submit();
            }
            );

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And I've created a small link:

```
<a href="#" id="btn1">Click here</a>
```

Comment: First append form to body and then append hidden field to form... Check it... I'm not sure... but try it

Comment: mixing jQuery with pure JS in this case seems to be bad idea...

Comment: Also, are you sure the form if generated properly ? Did you also take a look at the HTML generated to see if the input elements are in order? I think they might not be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    window.open('', 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
    $('<form></form>').attr('method','post').attr('action','url_to_post').attr('target','formresult').append('<input type="text" name="test" value="test_value"/>').submit();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8HFa/)

Comment: Yes it is working in Chrome. But not in FF 26.0. What could be the reason? Also I need to run this code once every 30 secs. How should I handle this case? Do I need to call window.open every 30 secs?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use FF. You may need to append that object to some invisible div and then submit. As for doing it every 30 seconds... I don't really understand how that supposed to work. Maybe simply put that function on other page that would be opened in new window? Or you need to open new window every 30 seconds? Sound like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

So, the whole popup window thing is a little 90s, isn't it?  Modals are definitely the way to go and via a simple framework such as bootstrap, you can ensure that it will be cross-browser compatible and even responsive.  Plus your interface will look a lot better.

just remember to include the bootstrap cdn:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

html:

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary">click me bro</a>

<div id="popup" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal's rock!!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action="url_to_post" target="formresult"></form>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

jquery:

```
    $('a').click(function(){   
    $('.modal-body form').empty().prepend('<input type="text" name="test"   value="test_value"/>');
    $('#popup').modal('show'); 
});
```

check it out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGkX5/)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing what Flash Thunder has done (he probably deserves more credit)

This is the fix that I found to his work

http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/a8HFa/11/

For some reason, IE won't respond to a submit event from a form unless its in the body.

I've only really added `$('body').append($form)` - this seems to fix it.